# Multiple sum in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sum

```
SELECT sum( plot_status = 'OPEN' ) AS OPEN 
     , sum( plot_status = 'SOLD' ) AS SOLD
FROM `tbl_plot`
GROUP BY `plot_status
```

This is giving

```
OPEN   SOLD
7       0
0       8
```

How to make it

```
OPEN  SOLD
7      8
```

Or is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

just remove the `GROUP BY` clause and it will work.

```
SELECT sum( plot_status = 'OPEN' ) AS `OPEN` ,
       sum( plot_status = 'SOLD' ) AS SOLD
FROM  `tbl_plot`
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is present plot_name or id then group by that not by plot_status:

```
SELECT sum( plot_status = 'OPEN' ) AS
OPEN , sum( plot_status = 'SOLD' ) AS SOLD
FROM `tbl_plot`
GROUP BY //`plot_name or plot_id
```

This will work for you for individual plot.
And if you don't want that then remove the group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

select * from
(
select sum( plot_status = 'OPEN' FROM `tbl_plot` ) AS OPEN
select sum( plot_status = 'SOLD' FROM `tbl_plot` ) As Sold
)tbl